# Skip first line while reading CSVfile in Java

Tags: java, list, file, parsing

While reading a CSV file, I need to ignore the first line. First row has date and heading of the CSV which I don't need to read.

I have to read only from the second row onward. Can anyone please help me?

```
String csvFilename = "C:\\Data\\csv_files\\REPORT.csv";
String filterCSV = "C:\\Data\\csv_files\\Output.csv";
CSVWriter write = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filterCSV));
CSVReader csvR = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename)); ---- 
List<CSVData> list = csv.parse(col, csvR);

for (Object object : list) {
    ------
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
 List<CSVData> list = csv.parse(col, csvR);
 list.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you didnt write the CSVReader class by yourself then this constructor will skip the first line of the file:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ',', '\'', 1);
```

Comment: I will try these options and let you know the results. thanks for the help

Comment: CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ',', '\'', 1); - this worked as expected.
  Can you please explain what is '\'' means?
  
  =================================================================
 
  I have also tried to use list.remove(0). But it gives empty csv as output.
  
  for (Object object : list)
  {
     
     CSVData csvdataBean = (CSVData) object;
            System.out.println("inside List object" + csvdataBean.getTransferDate());  =----- It returns null value when I use list.remove(0)
            
           }
           
           Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Before reading the entire data in a while loop using **BufferedReader** use **br.readLine()** then first line of **csv file** will be eliminated, then read the remaining contents using **readLine()** function.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
    String line = " ";
    br.readLine();
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the methods in CSVParser.java

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, 
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("firstColHeader","secondColHeader").withFirstRecordAsHeader().withTrim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip(int numberOfLinesToSkip)` method from CSVReader class.

users.csv:

```
firstName,lastName
Edward,Norton
Brad,Pitt
```

My Spring Boot example:

```
implementation "com.opencsv:opencsv:$openCsvVersion"

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

    @Value("${users.csv.file.name}")
    private String usersCsvFileName;

    public void fillUsersFromCsv() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        var resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:csv/" + usersCsvFileName);

        try (var inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
             var inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
             var csvReader = new CSVReader(inputStreamReader)) {
            csvReader.skip(1);

            String[] nextRecord;
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                var firstName = nextRecord[0];
                var lastName = nextRecord[1];

                var user = User.builder()
                    .firstName(firstName)
                    .lastName(lastName)
                    .build();
                users.add(user);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to read users from usersCsvFileName file: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        userRepository.saveAll(users);
        log.error("{} users from usersCsvFileName successfully saved to DB", users.size());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to add into `List` like `ArrayList` and then remove `index[0]` like this:

```
list.remove(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer is just repeating the same thing that Pete B.'s answer above says.